# Changing direction of List Grid Ant.Design

Tags: antd

Is there a way to change Ant.Design's List Grid? It fills in Items from left to right. I'd like items to roll from top to bottom first, then left to right. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common problem with the grid layout. Only solution is to use css tricks (column count) like following

```
<Row style={{ minHeight: "800px",lineHeight:"0",columnCount:"2" }}>
{
  Object.keys(GalleryImages).map(imageKey => {
    return (
      <Col span={24}>
        <img src={GalleryImages[imageKey]} alt={imageKey} height="100%" width="100%" />
      </Col>
    )
  })
}
</Row>
```

I hope this would help.